# How close the mean and variance be?

Tags: poisson-regression

I need to use GLM for count data. I'm thinking Possion GLM. How close mean and the variance be, to say they are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about overdispersion you can switch to the negative binomial distribution. I usually switch because the biological and ecological data I deal with is generally overdispersed. Subjectively, I switch for anything greater than 1.2, but for me I am generally dealing with values of 2 to 3.

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept the answer if you want.